# When publishing apk to Google Play, some localizations got removed

Tags: android, localization, google-play

I'm suddenly getting this difference from the previous version when trying to upload a new version of my app to Play:

[image: Apk Localizations removed]
[image: Apk Localizations list]

I use only default string values, most of them hardcoded, as my app only supports one language so far.
Anyway, I haven't changed anything related to locales/languages to this last update.

when googling about this, the only reference I fount was [this link](http://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/36252-build-1142-adds-new-languageslocalization-to-the-apk/). I was using an outdated version of facebook sdk, but updating it didn't brought my Localizatons back... alse I don't use Corona SDK...

how will this affect my app's distribution? Is it like fewer people will have access to it? Or users will get some screens in the wrong language?

Comment: Interesting - I just had the opposite experience. I only support English, and now Google Play is telling me I've added 55 localizations.

Comment: The Facebook SDK also adds Spanish, and Hebrew (twice).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the opposite effect (like Seth said) after adding the "Google Play Services" library to my project. Maybe you removed this or another library (that had supported all of this languages) from your main project.

Comment: So I've removed/changed the way I'm importing some libraries (namely google play services for froyo, support-v4 and zxing) and all localizations are back! I even got the hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE feature removed. Anyway, for those asking why did your supported devices number changed, this link may be useful: http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html