# Translate PlacePicker UI from Google Play Services

Tags: android, localization, google-play-services, google-places-api

I have included the [PlacePicker UI](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) from the **Google Play Services**. As the app in which I have added this component is available in 26 different languages, I want to make sure all `strings` are also translated within this UI.

In the documentation there is no detail on how to translate its strings, nor is there any information available in which languages the **Google Play Services** are available.

How do I find out which languages are already supported, or which `strings` I have to translate for this UI component?

Answer (score 0):

For the supported language in the Google Play Service, this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/table/4419860?hl=en) can show you the lists of language that the Google Play service supported.

Now, for translation of language, you can use [localization](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/localization-checklist.html) for that.

The important step in preparing for localization is identifying the countries where you’ll distribute your apps and the languages spoken there. Localizing your apps is particularly important in countries where there is a large market opportunity and English or another international language is not widely used.

Here are the lists of topic that you can learn from this documentation.

1. Identify target languages and locales
2. Design for localization
3. Manage strings for localization
4. Translate UI strings and other resources
5. Test your localized app
6. Prepare for international launch
7. Support international users after launch

If you already have an application, then this [one](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3125566?hl=en) is also applicable for that.

For more information, check this related SO question. You can get more ideas from here.

- [Play Store app localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000604/play-store-app-localization)
- [When publishing apk to Google Play, some localizations got removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21380565/when-publishing-apk-to-google-play-some-localizations-got-removed)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I know everything about localizcation. I just need to find out how to localize the specific Google Places Picker UI, as the strings which are displayed are nowhere documented, nor are there any details on which languages are supported by this component

Comment: Places Picker is part of Google Maps API. So here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport) of the supported language in Google Maps API.